# python - MySQL installation link.exe failed with exit status 1120

Tags: python, mysql, sql, installation, mysql-python

When I try to install MySQL, I get error 1120. I am unable to understand why. I have python version 3.5 32 bit. Below is the part which shows all the errors & warnings:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\users\noni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include -Ic:\users\noni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(192): warning C4005: 'isnan': macro redefinition
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(264): note: see previous definition of 'isnan'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(203): warning C4005: 'SIZEOF_OFF_T': macro redefinition
    c:\users\noni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include\pyconfig.h(346): note: see previous definition of 'SIZEOF_OFF_T'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(301): warning C4005: 'HAVE_STDDEF_H': macro redefinition
    c:\users\noni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include\pyconfig.h(675): note: see previous definition of 'HAVE_STDDEF_H'
    _mysql.c(297): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(327): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(623): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(624): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(625): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(626): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(627): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1118): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1161): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1165): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1532): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt" /LIBPATH:c:\users\noni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\noni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86" kernel32.lib advapi32.lib wsock32.lib mysqlclient.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__mysql build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.5\_mysql.cp35-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.cp35-win32.lib
       Creating library build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.cp35-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.cp35-win32.exp
    mysqlclient.lib(typelib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(viosslfactories.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_winfile.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_messnc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_thr_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _printf
    build\lib.win32-3.5\_mysql.cp35-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix it somehow, because I have the same issue

Comment: @NikolaiNikolov Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Did anyone find the solution to this ? I find other related posts, where it has been suggested to install `MySQL Connector C 6.0.2, 32 bit ` and ensure it gets installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL`. The above error is the one I'm getting after doing that. I also tried installing the `64 bit` of the `Connector C 6.0.2` and copying the folder manually from `Program Files\MySQL` to `Program Files (86)\MySQL`. That also gives me `62 unresolved externals` and the error more or less is similar.

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728705/mysql-python-install-failed-with-exit-status-1120 I wasted a lot of time on this so hopefully, this answer will same someone else's time. The problem was that I was trying to install `MySQL-python` while using Python 3.6.2 but that is only for Python 2. I tried installing `mysqlclient` instead and it worked fine.