# MySQL-python install failed with exit status 1120

Tags: python, mysql, pip, mysql-python

So I tried running `pip3 install MySQL-python` and I got these error messages

```
  mysqlclient.lib(typelib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(viosslfactories.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_winfile.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_messnc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_thr_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _printf
    build\lib.win32-3.6\_mysql.cp36-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-pz867vb9\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-87_rnd_9-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pz867vb9\MySQL-python\
```

I have Microsoft Visual Studio installed as well as the MySQL connector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MySQL-python` is only for Python 2. For Python 3 you need `mysqlclient`, `mysql-connector` or `PyMySQL`.